# Alternate character using python

Tags: python-2.7

How do you great program that reads a string and makes each alternate character an Uppercase and each other alternate character a lowercase character.

Comment: you should iterate through the characters of the string and work on each character - check the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231371/who-can-i-change-case-in-python-make-upper-lower-and-vice-versa-python#answer-41448194

Comment: Possible duplicate of [who can i change case in python make upper lower and vice versa python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27231371/who-can-i-change-case-in-python-make-upper-lower-and-vice-versa-python)